# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP VBScript performance issues in Windows 8 but not Windows 8.1 or Window 7. How to fix?

Tags: windows, vbscript, msxml

I've got a VBScript that is making use of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP so I can retrieve some data from a remote server.  The script is working fine, but there is a serious performance issue in Windows 8.  The performance issue is not apparent in Windows 8.1 or Windows 7--it only manifests in Windows 8 and I'm uncertain as to why.  I am posting this question because the performance hit is significant--about five to eight seconds delay.

Here is the part of the script that makes use of it:

```
 set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 oHTTP.open "POST", sUrl, false
 oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
 oHTTP.send sRequest
 HTTPPost = oHTTP.responseText

 echo HTTPPost
```

Please note that it's not that this code *doesn't* work, it's just that it takes forever (i.e. eight seconds and sometimes more) to retrieve the data.   On the other machines, accessing the same URL, there is virtually no wait time--all that's being requested is a json string.

I've updated Windows 8 with all of Microsoft's updates.  I am running this on a Parallels virtual machine and am unable to understand why there is a performance issue when there is 100GB available in the HD and I've assigned 8GB to the VM.  I've scoured SO and Google to try and pinpoint a similar issue but could not find anything.

Comment: Your whole code isn't there such as `srequest` contents and type. Fiddler from www.telerik.com is from an ex MS programmer who has taken his private project to his new job. It will show you client - server interaction. It is a HTTP debugger.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Yes, I've played a bit with Fiddler in the past.  I will look into using that for debugging.  Much appreciated for the suggestion.